How to filter a DataFrame with different conditions for each column
I have a DataFrame where for each column I only want to show specific values based on the index, but these conditions are different for each column. This is what it looks like:
data = {'a': [1,2,3,4,5],
        'b': [10,20,30,40,50],
        'c': [1,1,1,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df:
   a   b  c
0  1  10  1
1  2  20  1
2  3  30  1
3  4  40  1
4  5  50  1

I now want to take values where index <3 for 'a', index <2 for 'b' and index = 4 for 'c'. Resulting in:
     a     b    c
0  1.0  10.0  NaN
1  2.0  20.0  NaN
2  3.0   NaN  NaN
4  NaN   NaN  1.0

I tried the following:
import pandas as pd

df_a = df.loc[df.index<3, 'a']
df_b = df.loc[df.index<2, 'b']
df_c = df.loc[df.index==4, 'c']

df_result = pd.concat([df_a, df_b, df_c], axis=1)```

Which gives the desired result, but is there a more efficient way to do this? So if I would have a list for the "<" condition and a list for the "=" condition, then could I create the resulting filter in one go? It is fine if the NaNs become zeros, because that is what I want in the end anyway.

Try setting the conditions like conditon_a = df.index < 3 and then use np.where from numpy library

Another possible solution, whose steps are:

The np.stack function stacks these boolean conds, resulting in a 2D array, which is then transpose to align correctly the mask with the original df.

The [np.where]2 function then evaluates these conds, returning the element of df if True, and NaN otherwise.


conds = [df.index < 3, df.index < 2, df.index == 4]

pd.DataFrame(
    np.where(np.stack(conds).T, df, np.nan), 
    columns=df.columns).dropna(how='all')


Or, even simpler, using pandas where as @mozway suggests in a comment below (thanks!):
conds = [df.index < 3, df.index < 2, df.index == 4]

df.where(np.stack(conds).T).dropna(how='all')


Output:
     a     b    c
0  1.0  10.0  NaN
1  2.0  20.0  NaN
2  3.0   NaN  NaN
4  NaN   NaN  1.0


You need to add .dropna(how='all') to match the expected output. You could simplify to df.where(np.stack(conds).T).dropna(how='all') ;)

I am afraid I do not quite understand your comment: does not my output match the expected one, @mozway?

Not sure if this is critical to OP, but row 3 gets deleted in their expected output.

:-) Ah!, right, @mozway! I had not noticed the row 3 missing!!! Thanks!

Thanks, this is what I was looking for as I need to do this many times and feel that this could be more efficient than concatenating.

Your approach is good, you could automate it with a dictionary comprehension and operator:
from operator import lt, eq

conditions = {'a': (3, lt),
              'b': (2, lt),
              'c': (4, eq),
             }

out = pd.concat(
    {c: df.loc[op(df.index, val), c] for c, (val, op) in conditions.items()},
    axis=1,
)

Variant using strings and query:
conditions = {'a': '<3',
              'b': '<2',
              'c': '==4',
             }

out = pd.concat(
    {c: df.query(f'index{v}')[c] for c, v in conditions.items()},
    axis=1,
)

# or
conditions = {'a': 'index<3',
              'b': 'index<2',
              'c': 'index==4',
             }

out = pd.concat(
    {c: df.query(v)[c] for c, v in conditions.items()},
    axis=1,
)

Output:
     a     b    c
0  1.0  10.0  NaN
1  2.0  20.0  NaN
2  3.0   NaN  NaN
4  NaN   NaN  1.0

The query approach makes it easy to define complex conditions:
conditions = {'a': 'index<3',
              'b': 'log(a)>1',
              'c': 'a-2*c==0',
             }

out = pd.concat(
    {c: df.query(v)[c] for c, v in conditions.items()},
    axis=1,
)

#      a     b    c
# 0  1.0   NaN  NaN
# 1  2.0   NaN  1.0
# 2  3.0  30.0  NaN
# 3  NaN  40.0  NaN
# 4  NaN  50.0  NaN


Thanks, this approach looks like it is doing the same as what I came up with, from an efficiency perspective. but this idea might come in handy in other situations.
